# Crontab executes but nothing happens (python file)

Tags: python, cron

I set up a crontab file to execute a python file every minute however it states it executed but no file is generated.

crontest1.py file contains:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open('/APPS/CronRun/crontest/dummy1.txt','w')
    f.write('hello world it is a file')
    f.close()
```

Crontab file:

```
    # /etc/crontab - root's crontab for FreeBSD
#
# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/etc/crontab 194170 2009-06-14 06:37:19Z brian $
#
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
#
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    who     command
#
*       *       *       *       *       root    /APPS/CronRun/crontest/crontest1.py
11      11      *       *       *       root    /usr/bin/find /APPS/* | grep python | grep core | xargs rm
14      14      17      *       *       root    /APPS/CronRun/Report/report.py
```

The crontab executes but no file appears.

I tried a simple date >> datelog.txt 
which works via crontab but the python file does not seem to execute.

The python file works if executed manually from the shell but not via crontab

I have tried explicitly stating: python /APPS/CronRun/crontest/crontest1.py in the crontab file, but this does not work

I have previously added cron jobs that work fine and still execute daily without any issues

e.g

```
31,01   *       *       *       *       root    /APPS/CronRun/makelist/list.py
```

Comment: Have you rebooted the system / restarted cron?

Comment: I just need a clarification here: I have used cron but only with executables or shell scripts. Can cron also execute Python scripts? I mean, doesn't it need a command like `python abc.py`?

Comment: @DDS assuming the OP is editing with `crontab -e` the daemon should be restarted automatically

Comment: @kiner_shah if the file is executable `chmod +x file.py` then all is fine — it just executes the program

Comment: @SamMason, I see. Thanks for the info! :-)

Comment: @nch what happens if you put a `print("hello world")` statement somewhere outside of your `if` block, does this appear if you run it manually and from whereever you're seeing cron output

Comment: @nch, you can try logging the result in a separate file. Like this: `/APPS/CronRun/makelist/list.py > /APPS/CronRun/makelist/log_python_script`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code without :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

f = open('/APPS/CronRun/crontest/dummy1.txt','w')
f.write('hello world it is a file')
f.close()
```

Maybe " crontest1.py " is executed by crontab as a module - not "**main**".

If that doesn't help try to update the Python.

> Python 3.1.x and lower

may be the reason.